# Update input based on a radio button selection in the properties pane

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts, react-webpart

I'm trying to update a input field value in the properties pane, based on a radio button selection, but its not changing.

I'm sure it'll be something simple-ish!
I've looked about but can't find a solution, hence this post.

If I don't set a default value in the properties of manifest.json file, it sets when I select once but it doesn't change when I switch between the radio buttons.

here's an example of what I've tried:

```
if(this.properties.radioButton === "radio1"){
    textField = PropertyPaneTextField('linkLabel', {
              label: "Label",
              value: "radio1 selected"
    })
}
if(this.properties.radioButton === "radio2"){
    textField = PropertyPaneTextField('linkLabel', {
              label: "Label",
              value: "radio2 selected"
    })
}

 return {
  pages: [
    {
      groups: [
        {
          groupFields: [textField]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
 };
```

Any help would be much appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the `onPropertyPaneFieldChanged` method to detect changes to property pane field values. When the radio button value changes, you can change the value of the text field.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/sp-webpart-base/basewebpart?view=sp-typescript-latest#@microsoft-sp-webpart-base-basewebpart-onpropertypanefieldchanged-member(1)

Here's some sample code.

```
export interface ISpfxPropertyChangeTestWebPartProps {
  radioButton: string;
  textField: string;
}

protected onPropertyPaneFieldChanged(propertyPath: string, oldValue: any, newValue: any): void {
  super.onPropertyPaneFieldChanged(propertyPath, oldValue, newValue);

  if (propertyPath == "radioButton") {
    this.properties.textField = newValue;
  }
}

protected getPropertyPaneConfiguration(): IPropertyPaneConfiguration {
  return {
    pages: [
      {
        header: {
          description: strings.PropertyPaneDescription
        },
        groups: [
          {
            groupName: strings.BasicGroupName,
            groupFields: [
              PropertyPaneChoiceGroup("radioButton", {
                label: "Radio",
                options: [
                  { key: "radio1", text: "One" },
                  { key: "radio2", text: "Two" }
                ]
              }),
              PropertyPaneTextField('textField', {
                label: "Label"
              })
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  };
}
```

Comment: That worked at treat, thank you

Comment: Glad I could help